# MYSQL - how to merge this 2 tables to get a specific table output

Tags: mysql

I have been struggling and would like some ideas/thoughts on how to do this. Unfortunately, I inherited these tables from a former coworker and need to work with what I got. I want to some how merge Table A with Table B to get Table C.

Table A:

| ID | ID_P | IP_Type | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat | Animal | Henry |
| 2 | Cat | Apple |  |
| 3 | Cat | Bananas |  |
| 4 | Shark | Animal | George |
| 5 | Cat | Animal | Richard |

Table B:

| ID_P | Name |
| --- | --- |
| Cat | Henry |
| Cat | Gordon |
| Cat | Olivia |
| Cat | George |

I would like Table C with this specific merge pattern. I want to merge Table B into A but don't create duplicates if it has a match for ID_P and Name. This is using all MYSQL.

| ID | ID_P | IP_Type | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat | Animal | Henry |
| 2 | Cat | Apple |  |
| 3 | Cat | Bananas |  |
| 4 | Shark | Animal | George |
| 5 | Cat | Animal | Richard |
| NULL | Cat | NULL | Gordon |
| NULL | Cat | NULL | George |
| NULL | Cat | NULL | Olivia |

Comment: Try `UNION` or `UNION ALL` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: On second thought, it doesn't seem to be easily achieved with a normal `UNION` or `UNION ALL`

Comment: i think it's possible ... i would do a union with Table A and B with just the two columns (ID_P, NAME) to get the super set and that result would LEFT JOIN with Table A to get Table C

Comment: I mean yes.. but I was suggesting a normal union without any additional operation (like LEFT JOIN as you mentioned). But when I tried it myself, I couldn't get the expected result so my suggestion of "Try UNION or UNION ALL" is lacking the additional operation. XD

Comment: You start with a nonsensical schema. And you end with a nonsensical result. I don't see that it's effort well expended. Start by fixing the data model.

Comment: @Strawberry unfortunately, it is an inherited mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a `UNION` between the full contents of table A and you can use a `LEFT JOIN` between A and B to look for non-existing records based on `ID_P Name` for the other half of the `UNION`.

Use literal `NULL`s to fill the columns that do not exist in the B side of the union, to produce the same column set.

```
-- Take all the cols from table A
SELECT
  ID,
  ID_P,
  IP_Type,
  Name
FROM tableA
-- Combine with a filtered set from B
UNION
SELECT
  NULL AS ID,
  b.ID_P,
  NULL AS ID_Type,
  b.name
FROM
  tableB b
  -- Join on ID_P and Name
  LEFT JOIN tableA a ON b.ID_P = a.ID_P AND b.Name = A.Name
-- NULLs on the left join mean non-matching
WHERE a.ID_P IS NULL
```

[Here it is in action](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/msL3tbqy9siRnvfYnvLVwM/0)